# Erro na instalação do ionic

Tags: ionic, ionic3

Olá, venho tentando intalar o ionic no meu pc ( WIN32 bits com NODEjs, java, java sdk, Git) instalado tudo certinho, porem ao seguir os passos como descritos no site oficial da ionic , sempre me apresenta com erros..

inicio a instalação `$ npm install -g ionic` onde ocorre tudo bem!

porem ao iniciar um projeto `$ ionic start myApp tabs` apresenta uma série de problemas e dependencias (na qual instalei e continuou apresentando diversos outros error), como apresentado no log abaixo..

```
> npm i
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.5.9: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning ECONNRESET: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular-devkit%2fcore failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
npm WARN registry Using stale package data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm WARN deprecated istanbul@0.4.5: This module is no longer maintained, try this instead:
npm WARN deprecated   npm i nyc
npm WARN deprecated Visit https://istanbul.js.org/integrations for other alternatives.
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...0.1.1","eslint-config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dione\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03-06T13_14_16_717Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

        npm i exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Comment: `npm i flatted` tenta esse comando.

Comment: na verdade tem algo errado no arquivo `eslint-config`, verifica se ele esta formatado corretamente etc....

Comment: @NeuberOliveira está formatado tudo certinho, não apresenta nenhum erro

Comment: @PéttrinMiranda `npm i flatted
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Dione\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Dione\package.json'
npm WARN @ionic/angular@4.0.2 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/core@^7.2.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.....`

Comment: Ta falando que falta @angular-devkit, `npm install -g @angular-devkit/core@latest`